# Mapping a table with multiple types with linq to sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I am working with a database that I am unable to alter in any way.

In it there is a table with multiple datatypes in, defined by a typeId.

Eg of table.

```
+------+----------+------+------------+-------------+
|  ID  |  TypeId  |  Nr  |  Descr     |  Value      |
+------+----------+------+------------+-------------+
|  1   |  1       |  1   |  Category  |  Customer   |
|  2   |  2       |  1   |  Language  |  English    |
|  3   |  2       |  2   |  Language  |  Spanish    |
|  4   |  1       |  2   |  Category  |  Supplier   |
+------+----------+------+------------+-------------+
```

I would like to map this table to two diffrent linq-to-sql models.

Currently I have it mapped to one as follows

```
[Table(Name = "StupidTable")]
public class AllTypesModel : IModel
{
    [Column(Name = "ID", IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "TypeId", CanBeNull = false)]
    public int TypeId { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "Nr", CanBeNull = false)]
    public int Nr { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "Descr", CanBeNull = true)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "Value", CanBeNull = true)]
    public string Value{ get; set; }
}
```

Is there any way to make a preselection based on a value in a column in the mapping?

The reason I would like to do this is based on that this table is used in associations in other models where Nr is the foreign key, and nr is not unique.

Edit:

The problem is when I would like to make an association using a type in the StupidTable. Right now I have to solve it like this:

```
private EntitySet<AllTypesModel> _categories;
[Association(Storage = "_categories", ThisKey = "CategoryId", OtherKey = "Nr")]
public EntitySet<AllTypesModel> Categories
{
    get { return _categories; }
    set { _groups._categories(value); }
}
```

This will get both a Category and a Languge on initiation, so I have to add another function:

```
public AllTypesModel JustACategory
{
    get
    {
        return _categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.TypeId == 1);
    }
}
```

to filter out just the categories. And given that this table has a lot of diffrent types it is a more costly operation then I would have liked.

Comment: You would need to define the item as an object.

Comment: @jdweng: yes, i can define objects but they will be indentical until i do any filtering with the query... i had hoped to be able to do the filtering before.

Comment: I do not know if you can (or cannot) do what you are trying to do but is the issue that you need to have different models based on your business logic or is that you do not want to filter the result set every time you access the entity?  If it is the later, I would create a couple of handy extension methods to filter my results.

Comment: @Jdweng Right now i am doing the filtering in the repository and that is working fine. The problem is when i would like to do an association between a table and the StupidTable. I'll update the question

Comment: I think you'd have better chances with Entity Framework.

Comment: Probably. But the project is to far gone to change over to EF I'm afraid.